# Integrating Intel-Media SDK with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, decoder, intel-media-sdk

Is there any available project on integrating Intel-Media SDK with Unity to decode and display videos on Unity on windows platform?

Or can anyone please help me on how to integrate Intel-Media SDK with unity exploiting the GPU capabilities to decode and display H264 encoded videos?